# multiple definition error using gnuplot

Tags: c++, g++, gnuplot

I read a lot about linking errors here at stackoverflow, but i don't know where my problem is.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "traffic.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
traffic t();
...
}
```

**traffic.h**

```
#ifndef _TRAFFIC 
#define _TRAFFIC
#include "gnuplot.h"

using namespace std;

class traffic{

public:
int step;
Gnuplot gpl;
...
#endif
```

After I'd made the .o files I wanted to link them all. The following error occures.

**shell**

```
g++ -o tr traffic.o main.o
main.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Gnuplot::tmpfile_num'
traffic.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

and a lot more multiple definition errors concerning Gnuplot.

gnuplot is only used in traffic.cpp

My question is: Where is my mistake?
By the way: are there too less informations to solve the problem?

Comment: You have a traffic.cpp file that we can't see, among other things. Construct a [testcase](http://sscce.org). `traffic t();` is wrong, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight from the **gnuplot.h** header

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// initialize static data
//
int Gnuplot::tmpfile_num = 0;
```

Seems like a bad practice of initializing statics in a header file when they should be done only in cpp files to avoid duplicate definition.

In your case you can fix it by not including the **gnuplot.h** header in any of your headers file but only in a cpp file. This will entail wrapping all calls to gnuplot header functions through a wrapper as it won't be available in any cpp but in one

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include "gnuplot.h"` in cpp file instead of `header` file means a `.h` file
then your files will be compiled